# Pre-pending and appending to a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My goal is to load an external tables log file into a CLOB column in an oracle database. I've been having issues with the max size you can insert at once but I am able to insert the whole file if I to_clob each line of the log file, concatenate and then insert them (as far as I'm aware this seems to be the quickest and easiest way?):

```
 insert into clob_insert_test values (to_clob('hfsdjhfjsdhfjksd')||chr(10)||to_clob('jhfklsdjfklsdjklfjdsjlk'));
```

My question is: 
I'm reading the file into a shell variable as below so what I need to do is pre-pend **to_clob('** to the beginning of each line of the variable and then append **')||chr(10)||** and remove the last **||chr(10)||** from the variable to finish. I can then use that variable in the SQL insert statement for the clob column. Is there a way I can directly do this on the variable rather than modifying the log file before reading it in?

```
log_content=$(<"$log_file")
```

Edit:

Sorry I don't think I was clear. Given the example log file I would expect the following variable contents.

Input file:

```
LOG file opened at 05/05/15 15:12:24

Field Definitions for table ext_loading
Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
```

Variable contents:

```
to_clob('LOG file opened at 05/05/15 15:12:24')||char(10)||to_clob('Field Definitions for table ext_loading')||char(10)||to_clob('Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a file like:

```
this is me||chr(10)||adfasdf
asdas||chr(10)||asdfasdfasdas
```

And you want it to become something like:

```
to_clob('this is meadfasdf')||chr(10)||
to_clob('asdasasdfasdfasdas')||chr(10)||
```

If so, you can use `sed` like this:

```
sed -e "s/||chr(10)||//" -e "s/^/to_clob('/" -e "s/$/')||chr(10)||/" file
```

That is:

- remove `||chr(10)||` once from each line.
- add `to_clob('` to the begining of each line.
- add `')||chr(10)||` to the end of each line.

And to store it in a variable:

```
log_content=$(sed -e "s/||chr(10)||//" -e "s/^/to_clob('/" -e "s/$/')||chr(10)||/" "$log_file")
```

---

### Update

To match what you *really* need, you can also do this:

```
line=$(sed -e "/./s/^/to_clob('/" -e "/./s/$/')||chr(10)||/" "$log_file")
```

Then the output is:

```
$ echo $line  # note, without quotes to have all of it together!
to_clob('LOG file opened at 05/05/15 15:12:24')||chr(10)|| to_clob('Field Definitions for table ext_loading')||chr(10)|| to_clob('Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE')||chr(10)||
```

And remove the last `||chr(10)||` with:

```
$ echo $line | sed 's/||chr(10)||$//'
to_clob('LOG file opened at 05/05/15 15:12:24')||chr(10)|| to_clob('Field Definitions for table ext_loading')||chr(10)|| to_clob('Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question to hopefully make it a little clearer. ||char(10)|| doesn't appear in the data but I need it to be added between lines so when it's taken from the database it doesn't just come out as one massive flat line.

Comment: But all that was needed was to remove the first expression from your answer. So I can mark as solved, thanks!

Comment: Oh, nice! I updated for future reference, also showing how to delete the last `||chr(10)||`.

Comment: What I have been using to remove the last 11 characters is log_content="${log_content%???????????}" is there any advantage to using your sed method over that?

Comment: @MattDamon it really depends on you. With my approach you know exactly what you are removing, whereas with yours you don't have to call any extra tool.